# How to make smart playlist that contain more than 1 artist

Tags: itunes, smart-playlist, playlist

I want to make smart playlist that contain more than 1 artist.

Example: 

I want to make smart playlist which artist are: Matchbox Twenty, Savage Garden, and Train. 

If I fill the box like this:
[image]
The playlist will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the first part

```
Match "all" of the following rules
```

to

```
Match "any" of the following rules
```